# Get the right output from Patreon through Zapier into Wordpress/PmPro

Tags: wordpress, zapier, patreon

Trying to assist with the setup of patreon tiers that go through zapier and then into Paid Memberships Pro on a wordpress website.

Going through the steps I get to https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgUr0.jpg Zapier has a how to on the website but it does not cover what is trying to be achieved here https://www.paidmembershipspro.com/add-ons/pmpro-zapier/ as it is inputting into PmPro from Patreon through Zapier

Comment: can you add more detail about what you've tried to your question? it looks like you're close. You're going to post the data in the docs to the url listed in settings

Comment: I'm the lead developer of PMPro. We're looking for good Zapier use cases and Patreon to Zapier to PMPro is a really good one. Can you use our contact form to get in touch so we can get more info to help you set this up?

Comment: The person I was assisting with this shall contact via the contact form @strangerstudios thank you for the response and I shall then post an answer once this is sorted to let others know as well.